# Is this Redux reducer example from the Pro React 16 book kosher?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm learning React and Redux, and I'm currently reading *[Pro React 16](https://www.apress.com/us/book/9781484244500)* by Adam Freeman. Consider this reducer [example](https://github.com/Apress/pro-react-16/blob/7c3f4d72ed07c97a578d0f06636014acf179c3d9/05%20-%20SportsStore/sportsstore/src/data/CartReducer.js) from Chapter 5. This reducer handles actions that modify a shopping cart. Here's part of the reducer:

```js
import { ActionTypes } from "./Types";

export const CartReducer = (storeData, action) => {
    let newStore = { cart: [], cartItems: 0, cartPrice: 0, ...storeData }
    switch(action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.CART_ADD: 
            const p = action.payload.product;
            const q = action.payload.quantity;

            let existing = newStore.cart.find(item => item.product.id === p.id);
            if (existing) {
                existing.quantity += q;
            } else {
                newStore.cart = [...newStore.cart, action.payload];
            }
            newStore.cartItems += q;
            newStore.cartPrice += p.price * q;            
            return newStore;
```

My understanding is that reducers *must* be pure functions, but this one seems to modify the store argument `storeData` when the product already exists in the `cart` array. Specifically, it updates the `quantity` property of the `existing` cart item, which comes from a shallow copy of `storeData`'s `cart` array. Thus, `storeData` will be modified as a side effect.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are correct.

Not only are you mutating the state (as you pointed out), but you are also returning this mutated object.

I believe you should only use the 'set' method from Immutable JS to update state in a reducer.

Answer (score 0):

<del>This is not a side effect.</del> I would call it a mutation of element used for new state creation.

This reducer <del>is pure</del> **is not pure** but **IMHO is good enough** (when you know pros/cons) :

- from the app perspective it does the job
- returns the same output for the same input (replayable action sequence)

Reducer role is to create a new state from current state and action. **The old state will no longer be used - this mutation doesn't matter.** <del>There is no requirement/restriction to leave the old state untouched.</del>

CONS: it can affect redux dev tools, undoing action can work incorectly (replay actions only in one direction - use `redux-undo` for real undo)

PROS: simplicity, smaller memory usage

There is a shopping cart example in [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/shopping-cart/src/reducers) - different (more flat) data structure.

Comment: I'm basing my comment on the redux docs: "It's very important that the reducer stays pure. Things you should never do inside a reducer: * Mutate its arguments ..." https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers

Comment: For strict purity you're right, I updated the answer.

Comment: I'm just learning, so you may be right -- it might be OK in the final analysis. But the Redux docs I quoted are quite clear: "You should never ... [m]utate its arguments."

Comment: Reducers in more general usage (not only redux) and from functional programming perspective should always be pure. In case of redux this exception is only a small drawback.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way of creating a reducer and to return the new state is like below:

```
export default CartReducer = (storeData = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
       case ActionTypes.CART_ADD: 
           return [..state, { ..action.cart }]
       default:
           return storeData;
    }
}
```

This way you create a new copy of your `state` and simply return the `new state`, you need also keep your reducer simple and avoid doing extra stuff like the logic of adding/updating the shopping cart in the reducer code.

You need also to create a `default action` and return untouched `state`.